# Event handlers base on user action in Plone

Tags: plone, zope

I want to do something programatically when user is created.

When user Is there any specific event to subscribe to ? It'd be great if I can do:

```
<subscriber
    for="IUserRegisteredEvent"
    handler=".registration.welcome_email"
    />
```

Also: Is IMemberData correct Interface that represents an user in Plone ? So that I can adapt it and do things like this:

```
user_activity = IUserActivityStream(member)
user_activity.log(event)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question is nearly identical to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5070055/is-there-an-easy-way-in-plone-to-get-email-notifications-when-new-users-join-the).
So the correct interface for the subscriber is:
[Products.PluggableAuthService.interfaces.events.IPrincipalCreatedEvent](http://zope3.pov.lt/trac/browser/PluggableAuthService/trunk/interfaces/events.py?rev=76611)

Comment: Thanks for that - I could have sworn that PAS wasn't actually emitting  that event, which I need, so I'm going to have to try again.