# How notify the administrator when someone join the portal (aka new member creation)

Tags: plone

in my plone 4.3.3 portal I need to notify the administrator (by email) when someone join the portal (aka new member creation).

How make it? Subscription event? Content Rule?

Thanks'
Vito

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an easy way in Plone to get email notifications when new users join the portal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5070055/is-there-an-easy-way-in-plone-to-get-email-notifications-when-new-users-join-the)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Register a subscriber for Products.PluggableAuthService.interfaces.events.IPrincipalCreatedEvent.